# How to watermark some vector data in an invisible way?

Tags: vector-graphics, watermark

I have a some vector data that has been manually created, it is just a list of x,y values. The coordinate of the points is not perfectly accurate - it can be off by a few pixels and it won't make any perceivable difference.

So now I am looking for some way to watermark this data, so that if someone steal the vector data, I can prove that it's indeed been stolen. I'm looking for some method reliable enough that even if someone take my data and shift all the points by a some small amount, I can still prove that it's been stolen.

Is there any way to do that? I know it exists for bitmap data but how about vector data?

PS: the vector graphic itself is rather random - it cannot be copyrighted.

Comment: "minor change to bump the question" is not something you should do. If people haven't paid enough attention to it, that's what a bounty is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the set of points all you can work with? If, for example, you were dealing with SVG, you could export the file with a certain type of XML formatting, a `<!-- generated by thingummy -->` comment at the top, IDs generated according to such-and-such a pattern, extra attributes specifically yours, a particular style of applying translations, etc. Just like you can work out from a JPEG what is likely to have been used to create it, you can tell a lot about what produced an SVG file by observation.

On the vectors themselves, you could do something like consider them as an ordered sequence and apply offsets given by the values of two pseudo-random sequences, each starting from a known seed, for X and Y translation, in a certain range (such as [-1, 1]). Even if some points are modified, you should be able to build up an argument from how things match the sequence. How to distinguish precisely what has been shifted could do with a bit more consideration, too; if you were simply doing `int(x) + random(-1, 1)`, then if someone just rounded all values your evidence would be lost. A better way of dealing with this would be to, while still rendering at the same screen size, multiply everything by some constant like 953 (an arbitrary near-1000 prime) and then adjust your values by something in that range (viz, [0, 952]). This base-953 system would be superior to a base-10 system because it's much (much *much*) harder to see what's happening. If the person changes the scaling, it would require a bit more analysis of values, but it should still be quite possible. I've got a gut feeling that that's where picking a prime number could be a bit helpful, but I haven't thought about it terribly much. If in danger or in doubt in such matters, pick a prime number for the sake of it... you may find out later there are benefits to it!

Combine a number of different techniques for best results, of course.